# Set new event target in Javascript function

Tags: javascript

The following onload-function should be used to execute all onclick-functions of class(default). However the excuted eval function does not provide the current target. Therefore I try to set it manually with a new Event... Somehow this code does not allow to set the target new. Pls can you help me out?

<--label onclick="tabbed('tabcpan-editElm')" class="default">Editor<--/label>

window.onload = function(){

var list = document.getElementsByClassName("default");

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

var event = new Event("eventName"); list[i].dispatchEvent(event);

```
eval(list[i].getAttribute("onclick"));
```

}
}

Comment: Doesn't `list[i].click()` work on its own?

Comment: avoid using eval function for security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you want to achieve. But I made this example because I think it's what you're looking for.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("default");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].click();
    }
}

function tabbed(x) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<label onclick="tabbed('one')" class="default">Editor 1</label>
<label onclick="tabbed('two')" class="default">Editor 2</label>
<label onclick="tabbed('three')" class="default">Editor 3</label>
```